# How to add a name attribute to a textarea?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I am currently struggling to add a name attribute to a `textarea`.

It's supposed to look like this in HTML:

`<textarea name="comment">Enter text here...</textarea>`.

For example in Ktor HTML DSL I can do this with an input field:

`textInput(name = "username")`, but it doesn't work for a textarea.

Is there a way to add a `name` property?

Maybe someone has some experience with Kotlin Ktor and HTML DSL.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add any attributes to a `textarea` create an instance of the `TEXTAREA` class:

```
get("/") {
    call.respondHtml(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        body {
            TEXTAREA(mapOf("name" to "some-name"), consumer).visit {
                // Add child nodes here
            }
        }
    }
}
```